# if collection does not exist create otherwise update in mongodb node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to mongodb. How to create a collection if not exists otherwise update.

```
try {
const { data } = Visit.findByIdAndUpdate(
  '',
  { $inc: { counter: 1 } },
  { new: true }
);
} catch (err) {
  return err;
}
```

This is my code to update a only one object Id. In that collection only one Object Id is present. When run this for first time, the collection is empty. So I want to check the collection exists. If exist update otherwise create a collection.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#std-label-upsert-behavior), like so:

```
const { data } = await Visit.findByIdAndUpdate(
  '',
  { $inc: { counter: 1 } },
  { new: true, upsert: true }
);
```

Upsert will:

- If document(s) match the query criteria, db.collection.update() performs an update.
- If no document matches the query criteria, db.collection.update() inserts a single document.

And the `insert` [behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#create-collection) if no collection exists is:

> If the collection does not exist, then the insert() method will create the collection.

Comment: I want check collection if exist before update collection.

Comment: @Sowmiya did you find a solution for this? For me, findOneAndupdate succeeds even if the collection doesn't exist. I want to create the collection if it doesn't exist.

Comment: No idea why this answer was down voted, maybe it wasn't clear enough that this is the proper solution. Therefor I added some details about the `upsert` behavior. @iAviator 

I recommend trying it out before assuming it doesn't work.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert You just gave the upsert code. It was not clear that you are trying to answer exactly what was asked. Now after the edit it seems fine.